# Why are my Trash items not showing?

Tags: nautilus, trash

There was a folder on my desktop, and I dragged and dropped it onto the trash icon on the bottom right of the screen to see if the folder would be deleted.

It got deleted.

But when I opened up the trash folder by clicking on that icon, the folder I had deleted was not there. I then clicked on the properties of the trash folder and it said that there are 113 items in the trash while at the bottom of the window it says there is 0 items in the trash.

I tried viewing hidden folders but nothing showed up. I also tried to open it as root but nothing showed up again.

So does anyone know how I can view the 113 items in the trash?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like you have some items in an old gnome trash folder instead of the newer xdg trash folder. Do you need to recover the files and could you specify what you're looking for?

Even if you find out what's wrong, this still should be reported as a bug:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs

Comment: Yeah I would like to recover the folder that I deleted, how would I be able to access the old gnome trash folder?

Comment: go to a terminal and type in `locate "Name of Folder"` make sure you get the name exact with case matches and everything. If the folder still exists, that will hopefully tell you where.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you probably have some unreadable files in **`~/.local/share/Trash`**. You could determine this by running `chmod +r ~/.local/share/Trash/*` in a terminal. If that does not work, you can open the folder directly and see if you can see anything in it.

*If it all fails, then as Martin said, report a bug.*

Comment: There were three folders in ~/.local/share/Trash. I checked all of them and there was nothing in all three folders. I then ran that chmod command but nothing happened

Answer (score 1):

There have been some changes in the trash directory location as gnome/glib have evolved. Try the following:

```
rm -rf ~/.Trash/*
rmdir ~/.Trash
rm -rf ~/.local/share/Trash/*
chmod 700 ~/.local/share/Trash/
```

Then put something in the trash. The new trash hierarchy will be created automagically. See the article [how to manage trash from command-line](http://karuppuswamy.com/wordpress/2010/06/08/how-to-manage-trash-from-command-line-in-gnome-delete-list-restore-and-empty/) for more examples.

Comment: That does not look like it helps to see the files in the trash - th question is to find the 113 files. It will delete them instead, if I see that right? (The cleanup like that makes sense to get it working again, but the OP explicitly wants to see the files, not to delete them!)