# Ubuntu 16.10 - deleted files don't go to trash and keep taking space

Tags: trash, hidden-files, 16.10

The trash seems to be empty, but the partition's trash folder (.Trash-1000) shows the deleted files and they keep taking up space. Is this a bug in the new version (16.10) released today? Everything was working fine a few hours ago before upgrading to the new 16.10 edition.

[image]

Comment: What? that's a completely different question. Do you use Ubuntu 16.10? Can you verify it doesn't happen to you please?

Comment: Yes i am using 16.10, it's not a bug, it's keep saving the files inside `~/.local/share/Trash/` if you didn't delete it by Shift+Delete

Comment: That's true, but it should also show them in the trash folder (the one that you get to via the trash icon in the taskbar). Currently, when I delete a file, it just goes to the hidden folder and is not shown in the trash folder.

Comment: Try to take a look here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/13655/why-are-my-trash-items-not-showing

Comment: Thanks, but in my case, it's not an old gnome trash folder. Every new file I delete goes into it. So gnome still uses it. Just doesn't show its content.

Comment: For your information : I filed a bug report -> https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1633527  Please confirm the bug to help other users who are experiencing the same problem in Ubuntu 16.10 too !

Comment: Thanks. I hope they fix this soon. It's really annoying.

Comment: My experience is exactly the same. Files deleted by right click go to the .trash-1000/files folder for their disk, but don't appear in the trash bin on the taskbar or through Trash in Nautilus unless they originally appeared on the / drive. This change coincided with any additional internal drives losing their own shortut in Nautilus. Even if mounted, you have to get to them via '+other'. Also. it is no longer possible to drag and drop into any of the top shortcuts in Nautillus. However. if you use the Dolphin file manager, files deleted from anywhere appear in its Trash folder and can be drag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned earlier (see my comment to your question), I filed a bug report which was merged with this report -> https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/glib2.0/+bug/1633824. The root cause could be located - it was an issue with the `glib2.0` packages and finally a fix is released.

To apply the bug fix, enable the `yakkety-proposed` repository as described [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Testing/EnableProposed). Then open a terminal and execute : `sudo apt install libglib2.0-0 libglib2.0-bin libglib2.0-data`. Afterwards log out and back in and now everything regarding the trash will work as expected.

To revert back the configuration, disable the `yakkety-proposed` repository. Of course you alternatively can wait until the new `glib2.0` version is released to the `main` repositories.